# angular $httpBackend.when mocks - delay response NOT globally

Tags: angularjs, httpbackend, angularjs-ngmock, ngmocke2e

I found [this article](https://endlessindirection.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/angularjs-delay-response-from-httpbackend/) how to create an artificial server delay when using $httpBackend for mocking data.

Is there any way at all to have this on a per-mock basis? Perhaps something like:

```
    $httpBackend
        .whenGET(/\/my\/endpoint$/)
        .respond(data, 2000);
```

OR

```
   $httpBackend
        .whenGET(/\/my\/endpoint$/)
        .withDelay(2000)
        .respond(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [angular-mocke2e-maydelay](https://github.com/popduke/angular-mocke2e-maydelay)

if you use `bower`

```
bower install angular-mocke2e-maydelay
```

in *index.html*

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js">    </script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-mocke2e-maydelay/angular-mocke2e-maydelay.js"></script>
```

Add this to your app

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMockE2E', 'mayDelay'])
```

In the tests the unmocked `$httpBackend` can be used as below to delay the response.

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/foo.json').respond({foo:"bar"}, 3000); //delay 3s
$httpBackend.whenPOST('/bar',{foo:"bar"}).respond(200, "succeed", 5000); //delay 5s
```

This feature request is already posted in the angularjs [repo](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9341)